# What is the difference between Sync project with gradle files and Sync with File System?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have been through various answers with respect to the `Sync project with Gradle files`. But I couldn't find the major difference between *Gradle Files and File System*.

For making/building a project, we need to sync the project with Gradle files. But does it need to be done when are we using the `Sync using File system`?

Comment: Gradle Build helps you to compile your Android app into an APK while Gradle Sync will sync up all your Gradle dependencies to your Android project.

Answer (score 0):

In android studio when update comes project sync is necessary to work properly

If you working project then update android studio or update gradle dependencies you will need **sync project with gradle files** starting with Android Studio 3.1, the menu path is  `File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files` **OLD** go `Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`

If you update the project files added or removed files you will need **sync with file system ** `File -> Sync with Files System`

Comment: Thanks for giving out the information. Happy Learning :-)